# Pass SQLAlchemy Query to Base Jinja Template

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, python-decorators

I am creating an application using Flask, SQLAlchemy, and Jinja.  Almost every page in my application uses a `base.html` file (which is essentially a shell with a navbar and sidebar), and then builds upon that.  I display information in the `base.html` file that is the result of a SQLAlchemy query:

```
user.company.users.filter(User.account_approved == False).all()
```

and right now I am passing it to a single view by using:

```
@splash.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return render_template('templates/dashboard.html', pendingUsers=g.user.company.users.filter(User.account_approved == False).all())
```

However, this only allows the `base.html` view to have this information when I load the `/dashboard` route, and if I load any other route that uses the same `base.html` file, running `{{ pendingUsers}}` outputs not text.  How can I go about rendering that query in every route that uses `base.html`? I tried making the query directly in the jinja template, but I could not figure out how to do that (for example, running `{{ g.user.company.users }}` simply outputted the SQL query for that SQLAlchemy statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is not going to work because your query is not evaluated when you call it within render_template. Instead, the sql query string is sent as is to the template.

You can use a custom decorator since *only* want to do this for some views/pages.

```
def get_pending_users(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        pending_users = user.company.users.filter(User.account_approved == False).all()
        if g.pending_users is None:
           g.pending_users = pending_users
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

In your view, you can call it as:

```
@app.route('/',methods = ['GET','POST])
@get_pending_users
def whatever():
    return render_template('templates/dashboard.html')
```

Then, in your template, just call `g.pending_users`

```
 {{ g.pending_users }}
```

Comment: I only want to run this for certain pages, though (the ones that use `base.html`). How do I make this into a custom decorator that I can call before those pages?

Comment: But you said in your question "every page in my application uses base.html..". So I assume that every template will extend base.html, isn't it ?

Comment: I apologize, I misspoke and just modified the question.  Almost every page in the app uses it, but some pages do not.  Is this method still usable?